# Saleforce outbound change set equivalent of git diff

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Using the UI, as far as I can tell when you create an outbound change set from a sandbox in Salesforce you have to have thorough knowledge of every component type that you changed (and want to deploy to production) and then manually select each one of those components. Is there anything like a git diff for Salesforce to systematically show you what things have changed vs production? It seems like there should be.

I have Googled this and searched the Salesforce settings high and low. If it doesn't exist, I am shocked.

Answer (score 1):

There's DevOps Centre acting as "git for dummies", for admins who may not know every little thing they need to deploy. From what I remember it needs a publicly visible Github project. (I don't mean open source code, I mean "reachable from SF servers as opposed to a local Github installation visible only from your company's local network)

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.devops_center_overview.htm&type=5 Because you're right, it's an art. It's never "just add a new field to object". Do you need page layout? listview? report type, report? which profiles and permission sets?

And separate from that - read up about "source tracking". SF can keep track of all changes done in the org and download them to your local sfdx / vscode project with 1 command. It started as something for "scratch orgs" (mini sandboxes that exist for 30 days max) but you can benefit from "source tracking" in Dev, Dev Pro sandboxes too... This would help you pulling down changes from org to local disk but you still need some Git knowledge to commit your changes, you still need commands to deploy to non-tracked orgs (full copy sandbox, production org). https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/01/learn-moar-with-spring-21-sandbox-source-tracking

And of course there are paid tools (Gearset, Copado?) that offer the comparison  git branch-org or org-org comparison, incremental deployments... Feel free to poke the sales reps for a demo.

It depends if in your organisation SF is left to its own devices or do you have a mature IT team that would prefer to script the deployments to prod using existing CI (circle ci, jenkins, azure devops, github actions, gitlab ci...)

Comment: While I'm disappointed that SF doesn't offer a slicker UI solution, this is great info. Thank you.